# convert between image coordinates (i-j-k) and world coordinates (x-y-z) vtk in C#

Tags: vtk, dicom

Does anyone knows how can I convert from image coordinates acquired like this:

```
private void renderWindowControl1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] lastPos = this.renderWindowControl1.RenderWindow.GetInteractor().GetLastEventPosition();

        Z1TxtBox.Text = (_Slice1 + 1).ToString();
        X1TxtBox.Text = lastPos[0].ToString();
        Y1TxtBox.Text = (512 - lastPos[1]).ToString();
    }
```

into physical coordinates.
TX Tal

Answer (score 0):

VTK may have an elegant method call, but in general you will need to use the information in your image's image plane module (specifically Equation C.7.6.2.1-1).

http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/html/part03.html#sect_C.7.6.2

Comment: The problem is that lastPos  is the position in the render window, rather then in the dicom image. if the user is zooming in, the last pos position is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

in order to convert between a click and physical location: 
There is some insights I got from working on this project:

```
int[] lastPos = this.renderWindowControl1.RenderWindow.GetInteractor().GetLastEventPosition();
```

returns the pixel location of the click in the control. It is a problem because if the user zooms in, lastPos does not represent the location in the dicom.

The solution I have found, was to use vtkPropPicker class. Code example can be found [here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Images/PickingAPixel2) and [here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Images/PickingAPixel).

image_coordinate are in world coordinates but without the origin offset. which mean, that:
1. if we want to get the pixel location (in 512x512 grid): the x,y value should be normalized by pixel spacing, and image orientation. the value of these parameters can be acquired using the equation mentioned in the answer above me [Equation C.7.6.2.1-1](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/html/part03.html#sect_C.7.6.2).

```
vtkDICOMImageReader _reader;
reader.GetPixelSpacing();
reader.GetImageOrientationPatient();
```

2. If we need world physical location, we should add the origin offset for x and y:

   reader.GetDataOrigin();

As for Z axis: I didn't need it, so I am not sure.

That is my dime on the matter, maybe there are some more elegant ways, I haven't found them.